# The dynamic route parameter does not support Unicode languages other than English

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Official Documentation of NextJS 13 (beta) describes dynamic route parameters in [this link](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/page#params-optional).

***Explanation:***

```
app/shop/[slug]/page.js
```

To access slug, we use `params.slug`.

***Example:***

```
app/shop/this-is-shop/page.js
```

Here `params. slug` return -> `this-is-shop`.

**If we use another language other than english, for example in Hindi**:

```
app/shop/यह-दुकान-है/page.js
```

`params.slug` return -> `%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88`.

But it should return -> `यह-दुकान-है`.

That's the issue. How to fix this? Or a way to get an actual text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue related to Next.js. It's how URLs work. You can only have a limited number of characters in a URL. Others should be encoded. Here is a quote from an [article](https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/) from URLEncoder.io:

> A URL is composed of a limited set of characters belonging to the US-ASCII character set. These characters include digits (`0-9`), letters(`A-Z`, `a-z`), and a few special characters (`"-"`, `"."`, `"_"`, `"~"`).
>
> ASCII control characters (e.g. backspace, vertical tab, horizontal tab, line feed etc), unsafe characters like space, `\`, `<`, `>`, `{`, `}` etc, and any character outside the ASCII charset is not allowed to be placed directly within URLs.
>
> Moreover, there are some characters that have special meanings within URLs. These characters are called reserved characters. Some examples of reserved characters are `?`, `/`, `#`, `:` etc. Any data transmitted as part of the URL, whether in query string or path segment, must not contain these characters.

> So, what do we do when we need to transmit any data in the URL that contain these disallowed characters? Well, **we encode them!**

> URL Encoding converts reserved, unsafe, and non-ASCII characters in URLs to a format that is universally accepted and understood by all web browsers and servers...

What you are seeing is the encoded version of "यह-दुकान-है" as you can see in this example:

```js
console.log(encodeURI("यह-दुकान-है"))
```

If you want the initial value, use `decodeURI()`, like so:

```js
console.log(decodeURI('%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B9-%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88'));
```