# Next.js router.push encodes query parameters - pages directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to make a redirect using router.push to pass a query string, but when I try to pass a value in my param with special characters as a comma is encoding my URL. Is it possible to pass ',' into an URL using router.push?

I have tried a lot of things but I don't know how to make it work.

`router.push({ pathname: router.pathname, query: { ...router.query, pets: 'cats,dogs'}, })`

The resulting URL will be myurl?pets=cats%2Cdogs, I want it to be myurl?pets=cats,dogs.

Comment: also note that the previous router.query data shouldn't be changed

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/75438391/15288641.